# SQL group by problem

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have to write a query to database, that has such table:

```
TABLE HISTORY:
ID | ITEM_ID | USER_ID | DATE
```

and

```
ITEM TABLE:
ID | NAME | OWNER_ID
```

History table contains a records of all operations with items by users.
I have to write a query, that takes from HISTORY table all items, which are not in the hands of owner. So, it should take for each item last record and select from them only those, which holds in other than it's owner's hands.

I tried to write it using nested queries, but if I'm using such subquery:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, MAX(DATE) 
FROM HISTORY
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
```

I can't take ID of this record. So, I can't loop over the nested queries result's, because I don't know an ID of their ID's.

Could you help me?

P.S. And could you advise me to the future, how to take from queries with group by clause the columns, which not in group by statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that you want all items whose most recent history entry was made by a non-owner user. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
select h.item_id
from item i
    inner join history h
        on h.item_id = i.id and i.owner_id != h.user_id
    inner join (select item_id, max(id), max(date) as date
                from history
                group by item_id) mh
        on mh.item_id = h.item_id and h.date = mh.date
```

The above query assumes a datetime with some guarantee of uniqueness in the date column. If not, you might be able to use history.id if it is a perfectly auto-incrementing identity column and you promise never to let anyone mess with (ok, maybe not that strict, but you get my point).

In this case:

```
select h.item_id
from item i
    inner join history h
        on h.item_id = i.id and i.owner_id != h.user_id
    inner join (select item_id, max(id) as id
                from history
                group by item_id) mh
        on mh.id = h.id
```

Comment: Yes. I also thinked about joining subquery using date. But if in one day has been more than one operations with items. And they has same date. How it works?

Comment: I think you have a mistake: on h.item_id = i.id and i.owner_id != i.user_id - last condition: i.owner_id != i.user_id is not correct

Comment: Also, make date a datetime column so that you can actually know the time of the edit.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks a lot! But I still not understand, is there some way to write a query with group by clause, which will contain the fields in result, which not appear inside group by?

Comment: @llnur There's no way to get columns not specified in the group by list other than using aggregates on them. You may be able to join a subquery that is grouped back to the original table, but this tends to indicate poorly normalized data or poorly selected primary keys. In this case, your primary key is a "surrogate" key, which many database purists would criticize as a poor design. This primary key is related to the date and time of the action in the history table because it is auto incrementing and therefore, helps us find the most recent insert for a given item.

Comment: Note: I don't think there is anything wrong with your current database design. Understanding why purists might criticize your design can help you make design decisions and see possibilities like taking the max id to find the most recent insert.